# Getting Python SQL error - Must declare the scalar variable "@p1offset" when using Tkinter

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter

I am trying to run 2 SQL queries and output them each to 2 labels in Tkinter:

```
    self.output = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
    self.output2 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output2.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
```

I am getting a scalar variable error and I'm not sure what is causing this.
In Tkinter, I can't output multiple rows to a label so I have to create additional labels and put

```
            OFFSET 1 ROWS
            FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

in the second SQL query so I can display the second row on the second label.

Here is what I am trying:

```
def calculate(self):
    firstname = str(self.first_entry.get())
    lastname = str(self.last_entry.get())     
    license = str(self.lic_entry.get())
    if (firstname and not lastname and not license):  # "You entered first name."

        try:
            connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServer;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[0]
            if sqlstate == '28000':
                self.answer_label['text'] = "You do not have access." 
        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, L_LICNUMBER "      
            "FROM dbo.my_table "   # table name
            "with (nolock)"
            "WHERE FIRSTNAME = ?")
        Values = [firstname]
        cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        if results:
            self.output['text'] = (results[0]) # display  results

        else:
            self.output['text'] = "That name does not exist."

        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, L_LICNUMBER "      
            "FROM dbo.my_table "   # table name
            "with (nolock)"
            "WHERE FIRSTNAME = ?"
            "order by FIRSTNAME"
            "offset 1 rows"
            "fetch next 1 rows only")
        Values = [firstname]
        cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        if results:
            self.output2['text'] = (results[0]) # display  results
            connection.close()
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but you don't appear to have an `else` after that last if for the second query  (before the `connection.close()`)  Was that intended?

Comment: Yeah it was intended.  I placed it in there to try it and I'm still getting the scalar variable error.  I think it may have something to do with the users input being used as a variable.  It's only allowing me to use it once in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after searching all day.  I hadn't been able to find anything in Google.
OFFSET ROWS AND FETCH didn't work.

This does:

```
def calculate(self):
    firstname = str(self.first_entry.get())
    lastname = str(self.last_entry.get())     
    license = str(self.lic_entry.get())
    if (firstname and not lastname and not license):  # "You entered first name."

        try:
            connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerName;Database=myDatabBaseName;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[0]
            if sqlstate == '28000':
                self.answer_label['text'] = "You do not have access." 
        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, L_LICNUMBER "      
            "FROM dbo.my_table "   # table name
            "with (nolock)"
            "WHERE FIRSTNAME = ?")
        Values = [firstname]
        cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
        results = cursor.fetchmany(10)
        if results:
            self.output0['text'] = (results[0]) # display  results
            self.output1['text'] = (results[1])
            self.output2['text'] = (results[2])
            self.output3['text'] = (results[3])
            self.output4['text'] = (results[4])
            self.output5['text'] = (results[5])
            self.output6['text'] = (results[6])
            self.output7['text'] = (results[7])
            self.output8['text'] = (results[8])
            self.output9['text'] = (results[9])
            connection.close()

        else:
            self.output['text'] = "That name does not exist."
```

You'll have to create a group of LabelFrames, ListBoxes, or Messages to display your results.

```
    self.output0 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output0.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
    self.output1 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output1.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
    self.output2 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output2.grid(column=0, row=8, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
    self.output3 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output3.grid(column=0, row=9, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
    self.output4 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output4.grid(column=0, row=10, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
    self.output5 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output5.grid(column=0, row=11, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
    self.output6 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output6.grid(column=0, row=12, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
    self.output7 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output7.grid(column=0, row=13, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
    self.output8 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output8.grid(column=0, row=14, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
    self.output9 = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=20, width=830, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
    self.output9.grid(column=0, row=15, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=0)
```